# Help! How to derive the result related to Darboux derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, manifolds, lie-algebras, connections

First, define Darboux derivative. There is one Lie group $G$ and one manifold $M$. Let $\phi:M\rightarrow G$ be a smooth map. The Darboux derivative $\Delta(\phi):TM
\rightarrow M\times \mathfrak g$ of $\phi$ is given by

$\Delta(\phi)(X_x)=T(R_{\phi(x)^{-1}})(T(\phi)(X_x))$.

Second, suppose $V$ is a vector space. $f:M\rightarrow V$ and $\phi:M\rightarrow Hom(V,V)$ are both smooth maps. $\phi$ takes values in $GL(V)$. It is easy to get

$X(\phi(f))=X(\phi)(f)+\phi(X(f)),\quad X\in\mathfrak X(M)$

Here, $\phi(f)|_x=\phi(x)(f(x))$.

OK. Here comes my problem. It is said that $X(\phi)(f)=-\Delta(\phi)(X)(\phi(f))$. I tried to prove this relation, but I cannot get the sign correct. I will post my derivation:

Let's start with 
$\Delta(\phi)(X)(\phi(f))$. Suppose a curve $\gamma(t)$ in $M$ passing through a point, say $p=\gamma(t)\in M$ and $X$ tangent to it. We can evaluate it at $p$ in the following way

$\Delta(\phi)(X)(\phi(f))=\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} [\phi(\gamma(t))\phi(\gamma(0))^{-1}]\phi(f(\gamma(0)))$

Here, I treat $\phi(x)$ as a matrix and the term behind $\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}$ is a matrix multiplication. Further more, I get

$=\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}[\phi(\gamma(t))]\phi(\gamma(0))^{-1}\phi(\gamma(0))(f(\gamma(0)))
=\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}[\phi(\gamma(t))]f(\gamma(0))=\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}[\phi(\gamma(t))f(\gamma(0))]=X(\phi)(f)|_{\gamma(0)}$.

So where does the minus sign come from?

Comment: Since $\phi(f)$ is a function on $M$ with values in $G$ and not a function from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$ what does it mean to write $X(\phi(f))$? Also where did you find this definition of Darboux derivative? The only reference I know is Sharpe's Differential geometry.